# SQL statement for value from multiple field

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter

Currently I'm working on the project that has filtering function.
My project as a few field that user can choose.
Ex:Status,Created,Release,Date

Situation:- The user can filter the report based on all the field or any combination from the mentioned field.

If I choose the AND condition,then I need to supply all the condition that required. If I choose OR condition, it will give some wrong output if there is more than one field is chosed.

Any suggestion are really appreciated.

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand what it is you need.

Comment: Which database system do you use?

Comment: Well, are you trying to "AND" your conditions together or "OR" your conditions together?

Comment: @paqogomez, I would like to do filtering based on the condition that user have chosed. There is four condition for the filtering part, user can use one or more condition.so if I used the "AND",i need to supply all the four condition.will be having problem if the user just chose one of the condition.

Comment: @Guneli,i'm using microsoft acess.

Comment: @BillGregg, I'm stuck at that part because if I used the "AND",i need to supply all the four condition.will be having problem if the user just chose one of the condition.If I used the "OR", the output will different what the expected.

Comment: No, you don't have to supply all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test which values are passed and which ones aren't.  Assuming that values not passed in will be NULL, do this:

```
Select .....
from ....
where (Status = @Status or @Status is null)
and (Created=@Created or @Created is null)
and (Release = @Release or @Release is null)
and (Date = @Date or @Date is null)
```

Comment: I will give a try based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Your solution help me to solve the problem that I faced.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the presence of any of the parameters that the user can possibly specify, you can check and concatenate additional 'where condition' inside your function and run the select on the latest step. So, the initial select would looke like:

```
         select ....
         where 1=1
```

And after that by checking the parameters passed, you can add:
sql:=sql||' and .....'